# Can we get a tag for the 'at' command for Ubuntu?

Tags: feature-request, tags

There doesn't seem to be one and I use both cron (which has a tag) and 'at' at different times. I'm not able to add a tag at this time.

Tags just for more common commands would be very helpful. I would be able to help people with 'nedit' but no other editors, or 'alpine' but not other email interfaces.

Thanks!

Comment: We've been discussing this in the chat; I don't have a definitive stance on this yet, so I'll just post some data. My estimate of questions about `at` / `atd` is ~14... This [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/432226) looks legit enough, 23 results and 7 out the first 10 could legitimately be tagged with it. The only thing I'd like to add is that as Dan remarks in the comments under Thomas. W's answer currently those are completely unbrowseable due to the overwhelming number of posts containing the preposition "at". Something to think about before deciding.

Comment: `at` is one of those commands that when I Google it, I really don't get relevant results because `at` is one of those common words and Google might even filter it out when forming a query. I never would have thought to look for the tag 'schedule'.

Comment: Me neither, that's why for a moment I created the tag before seeing this discussion. And yes I believe that, same problem here. The point is only the number of questions which is a bit low to be honest. I don't know yet what to think about this. Once I do I'll either post an answer supporting this (if no one will have done it by the time) or upvote Thomas W.'s post.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need a tag for every software or utility tool.

The nearest tag is [schedule](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/schedule), I believe.  It should likely be coupled with [command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/command-line) for the `at` program and related questions. The [schedule](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/schedule) tag's tag wiki and excerpt are as follows:

> The schedule tag should be used for questions about scheduling events, like running applications or processes on a planned time.

This seems to fit, because `at` does this, according to its manpage (from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/at.1.html):

> **at** and **batch** read commands from standard input or a specified  file which are to be executed at a later time, using `/bin/sh`

Comment: I agree with `We don't need a tag for every software or utility tool`, but a tag for `at` does have one advantage. If you trying to search for something related to the `at` tool, it is really hard as it just a common word. For example, searching for `at` on askubuntu returns [36k results](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=at%20is%3Aq).

Comment: Don't forget [tag:command-line]!

Comment: It so happens that without having seen this question I created the tag... Obviously reverted since you guys are currently questioning it. I agree with the answer but I'm not sure... After all the command ships with Ubuntu by default, and the [question in question](http://askubuntu.com/q/729677/380067) really shouldn't be tagged with anything else since it's *very* specific to the tool.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure how many questions would have needed it (and weren't tagged with it because the tag never existed) / how many questions will benefit from it, but I think the two ponts above (mine and @Dan 's) should be taken into consideration. What do you think?

Comment: @Dan I think that, while the opinion is valid, if you search for 'at', the word 'at' is a keyword used super frequently in the English language.  It doesn't immediately mean all the questions are about the `at` software.

Comment: @kos considered and -1'd by me - we need to determine how many questions are actually asked about the `at` command - if there are only 10 it doesn't need a tag, but if there are 10000, then maybe.  The search posed by Dan earlier is a keyword search so there's thousands of *extra* items caught because 'at' is a frequent word in the English language, therefore that search is invalid.

Comment: @ThomasW. That was Dan's point, there is no way to search for questions about `at` currently because it is such a common English word. If we had a tag then people could search for it. (I don't necessarily support the idea, just clarifying that point)

Comment: @Seth there's only 52 questions related to `atd` which is what `at` works with - I can't tell time distribution but that sounds like a relatively infrequently used tag or question base

Comment: 52 is plenty enough for a tag *if* we decide we want one.

Comment: Lets just use Chat for now to discuss this - otherwise comments will be infinitely long